# PHP парсинг текста между тегами

Tags: парсер

Есть текст:

```
<cat>
<category id="12" title="Cat2" type="1">
<category id="22" title="Cat21" type="2">
<category id="23" title="Cat22" type="2">
<category id="24" title="Cat23" type="2">
</category>
<category id="13" title="Cat3" type="1">
<category id="333" title="Cat31" type="2">
<category id="334" title="Cat32" type="2">
<category id="335" title="Cat33" type="2">
</category>
</cat>
```

Как получить текст между

```
<category id="12" title="Cat2" type="1">ТЕКСТ</category>
```

и потом по циклу из этого содержимого получить значения id, title, type?

Comment: а там не xml,  а такое ужасно?

Comment: Нужна помощь именно с этим кодом.

Comment: можно попробовать [регулярку](https://regex101.com/r/RhZ8jW/1). Но это только если формат такой всегда.

Comment: Тоже думаю, что регулярка поможет, но я в регулярке не силён

Comment: `<category\s+id="(\d+)"\s+title="([^"]*)"\s*type="(\d+)">`

Comment: Только нужна ещё возможность извлечения текста между <category*></category> с type="1".

Comment: исправьте текст так, что бы он соответствовал вопросу.

Comment: Я так и написал выше

Comment: или category с type = 2 это и есть "текст"?

Comment: Да, category с type = 2 это ТЕКСТ

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ. В начале распарсим и вытянем "текст".

```
<?php

$re = '/<category\s+id="(\d+)"\s+title="([^"]*)"\s*type="(?<text>\d+)">(.*?)<\/category>/ms';
$str = '<cat>
<category id="12" title="Cat2" type="1">
<category id="22" title="Cat21" type="2">
<category id="23" title="Cat22" type="2">
<category id="24" title="Cat23" type="2">
</category>
<category id="13" title="Cat3" type="1">
<category id="333" title="Cat31" type="2">
<category id="334" title="Cat32" type="2">
<category id="335" title="Cat33" type="2">
</category>
</cat>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

А дальше аналогично вытягиваем с каждого "текста" уже подстроки (код ниже нужно вызывать в цикле для каждого найденного "текста").

```
<?php

$re = '/<category\s+id="(\d+)"\s+title="([^"]*)"\s*type="(?<text>\d+)">/ms';
$str = '<category id="22" title="Cat21" type="2">
<category id="23" title="Cat22" type="2">
<category id="24" title="Cat23" type="2">
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Отличный пример, спасибо! Буду его адаптировать под свою задачу.

Comment: внимательно сравните строки - слеша не хватает.

Comment: Тогда открываете фридла регулярные выражения и подгоняете до победного конца.